# How to use slash for =~ in Gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

I've use Tag($CI_COMMIT_TAG) to controll the event. 
I need to let Tag partially similar with my Tag name. 
Here is my yml 
My Commit_Tag usually like feature/dev/helloworld... 
How can i use slash in regex operator ? 
thanks

```
build_dev_job:
  stage: build
  only:
    variables:
      - '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^feature/dev_*/'
  script: 
    - export VERSION=$(date +%y.%m.%d)
    - docker build -t my_dotnet_app:$VERSION -f ./Dockerfile .
  tags:
    - core-runner
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitLab uses [re2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

To escape any characters as a literal, prefix it with `\`

`/^feature\/dev_*/`

Do keep in mind that you need to be mindful of YAML syntax and that your text is not interpreted as an escape sequence in your YAML.